# undefined variable notice when variable is defined

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

If I run this query without initializing  the`products` variable the code populates  the `<ul>` properly but I get an `undefined variable: products in...` error. I read in the php manual that when using prepared statements they return an extra (empty) result set as a result of having called the statement itself. Could this be the problem  or is it because the HTML renders first, sees the empty product variable and fires off this error because when I initialize `$products = ""`  all is fine. Curious to know exactly what's going on.

```
line 67: $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * from item WHERE user_id = '$pid'");

$sql->execute();

$products = "";

while($row = $sql->fetch())
{
  $item_id =  $row['item_id'];
  $user_id =  $row['user_id'];
  $item_name = $row['item_name'];
  $item_description = $row['item_description'];
  $date = $row['add_date'];
  $image = $row['photopath'];

  $products .= "<li><a href='item_view.php?pid=".$item_id."'><img src='$image' 
width='50' height='50'/></a> Item ID: $item_id UserID: $user_id NAME: $item_name Added on:    $date DESCRIP: $item_description</li>";
```

in the HTML

```
<ul>
line 112: <?php echo $products; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: show your line number ?

Comment: Is this an include? How is your HTML related to the PHP code if it's not inline?

Comment: HTML is under php in same file. ONly include is the connect

Comment: sorry i mean `undefined variable` should tell you at which line it happens

Comment: I don't know where you read that you get an extra result set when using prepared statements. I suspect you misunderstood.

Comment: @Barmar Right, I'm wrong. I read that about stored procedures

Comment: `$products` isn't being defined inside a function is it? Then it wouldn't be in scope later on in the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error is because you use `.=` to concatenate to `$products`. This requires the variable to already have a value, so it can add to it. If it's not initialized, you get a notice about an undefined variable the first time through the loop.

It treats this undefined value as an empty string, so the concatenation is effectively the same as an initialization on this first iteration. Future iterations behave normally, because the variable has a value then. But if you have warnings enabled, you get a notice on the first iteration, complaining about the uninitialized variable. It's always best to initialize your variables, rather than depending on this automatic coercion.

Comment: but isnt $products being initialized after first loop in the while?

Comment: The notice is happening _during_ the first loop in the while, isn't it?

Comment: The way I'm looking at it is during the first loop `$products` gets populated with the first loop of data, but I guess my logic is off

Comment: @rogerthat during the first loop it tries to evaluate the right side of the assignment and fails since `$products` has not been defined yet

Comment: @mario He said he gets the error message when he _doesn't_ have that initialization.

Comment: @mario you missed the last part of his question when he says that when he added `$products = "";` it started working

Comment: @mario read the question. I said when it is not initialized I get the error

Comment: @alfasin So the first loop evaluates the statement and the second loop populates?

Comment: @rogerthat Every time through the loop, it reads the old value of `$products`, and then appends to it to assign a new value. But the first time through the loop, there is no old value.

Comment: @Barmar right, but when does $product not have a value( even when I take out initializing it) The first time through doesn't it read the values of the $rows and then assign to $products? I feel I am getting redundant so I won't beat this to death just trying to understand how the while processes. I just read your update. SO first time through is more of a prepare?

Comment: @rogerthat It doesn't have a value until _after_ the assignment. But it needs the value to do the assignment, because you're using `.=`. Look at alfasin's answer, doesn't that make it clear?

Comment: @rogerthat First time through is not a prepare, it's the same as all the other times through. Doing the initialization _before_ the loop is a prepare.

Comment: I guess I'm just confused by the `.=`. I was under the impression during the first loop `$products` would have its value set to the values that came before it and that would be the initial value. I guess the next logical question is, is this the best approach?

Comment: `$products .= "string"` is just a shorthand for `$products = $products . "string"`. It doesn't behave any differently, they both depend on `$products` already having a value so it can be combined with the string.

Answer (score 2):

By doing `$products .=` you are actually doing: `$products = $products .` which is concatenation of products to itself and another string. Obviously it fails when product is not defined.